# Echo the textbox value without using submit and onclick function in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to echo the textbox value using php. Whatever user types characters in the textbox that  as to be displayed in the another textbox as well it as to  echo the amount in top As Value is:(Whatever is typed in the textbox)
Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzafz.png)

Here is the Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 
    if(!empty($_GET['a1']))
    { 
        $selected = $_GET['a1'];
    }
    else
    { 
        $selected = 'home';
    }

    if(!empty($_GET['a1']))
    { 
        $selected = $_GET['a1'];
    }
    else
    { 
        $selected = 'home';
    }
?>
<span class="r-text" style="font-weight:bold;">Value is</span>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="100" /> 100
    </label>
</br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="200" /> 200 
    </label>
</br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="300" /> 300 
    </label>
</br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value=" " /> Other
    </label>
</br>
    <input type="text" name="a1"/>
<br/>
<br/>
    Amount
    <input type="text" name="a2" />
<br/>
<br/>
</form>

<script>
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(e) {//jQuery works on clicking radio box
        var value = $(this).val(); //Get the clicked checkbox value
        var check = $(this); //Get the clicked checkbox properties (like ID, value, class etc) 
        $('.r-text').html('Value is '+value);// The class r-text after clicked checkbox print the line 'This was selected'
    });
</script>
<script>
    $('input[type=text]').click(function(e) {//jQuery works on clicking radio box
        var value = $(this).val(); //Get the clicked checkbox value
        var check = $(this); //Get the clicked checkbox properties (like ID, value, class etc) 
        $('.r-text').html('Value is '+value);// The class r-text after clicked checkbox print the line 'This was selected'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can add `onKeyUp` event handler.

Comment: Use Jquery . Assign Id to element  in which user will type and assign that id +val() to other text box where you want to display.

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: @user3168637 see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set value in textarea when user is typing in another textarea.By using `keyup` events.

```js
$('input[type=text]').on("keyup",function(){
       var value = parseInt($(this).val()); 
       if($.isNumeric($("input[name='a1']:checked").val())){
         value = parseInt($("input[name='a1']:checked").val()) +value;
       }
       $('[name="a2"]').val(value);
       $(".r-text").html('Value is '+value);
    })
    
    $('input[type=radio]').on("change",function(){
        var textBoxVal = parseInt($("input[type='text'][name='a1']").val()); 
        var selectedVal = parseInt($("input[type='radio'][name='a1']:checked").val());
         if(!$.isNumeric(textBoxVal)){
           textBoxVal = 0;
        }
        if($.isNumeric(selectedVal  )){
         textBoxVal = parseInt(selectedVal) +textBoxVal;
       }
       $('[name="a2"]').val(textBoxVal);
       $(".r-text").html('Value is '+textBoxVal);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="r-text" style="font-weight:bold;">Value is</span>
<form action="" method="post">

    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="100" /> 100
    </label></br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="200" /> 200 
    </label></br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value="300" /> 300 
    </label></br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="a1" value=" " /> Other
    </label></br>
    <input type="text" name="a1"/><br/><br/>
    Amount
<input type="text" name="a2" /><br/><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onKeyup event on text box that contain user input. and fill your required text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onblur() function from your HTML tag. 
onblur() is a JavaScript function. Display the contents of the text box from this function.